# How to copy one array to another array which is not in same class in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, nsarray

Hello
I want to copy elements of one array on another array which is in other class.
For that I have tried various ways like

Both arrays are not in same class.
For eg secondArray is in first.h file and array in in second.h file
then when I have made the object of second.h class like this

```
second *sec; //(in first.h)
```

and synthesize it
and then I tried to copy array like this
    sec=[[Second alloc]init];
    sec.array=secondarray;
but when i am accessing array in second class it is showing array is null

Does anyone have any idea about this? or any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something along these lines, I have not seen your code so this is probably not an exact solution to your problem, but hopefully it will help you understand the message passing required to solve your problem.

```
//FirstClass .h file
#import @"SecondClass.h"
@interface FirstClass : NSObject {
    NSArray         *firstArray; 
    SecondClass     *sec; 
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray        *firstArray; 
@property(nonatomic, retain) SecondClass    *sec; 
@end

//Add this to FistClass .m file
@synthesize firstArray, sec; 

-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        sec = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
        firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:sec.secondArray];
    }
    return self; 
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [firstArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

//SecondClass .h file
@interface SecondClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray          *secondArray;  
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray     *secondArray; 
@end

//Add this to SecondClass .m file
@synthesize secondArray; 

-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Obj1", @"Obj2", @"Obj3", nil];//etc... 
        //Maybe add some more objects (this could be in another method?)
        [secondArray addObject:@"AnotherObj"];

    }
    return self; 
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [secondArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to write this code in init method?because i already have objects in secondarray which is coming from xml parsing

Comment: No, as long as secondArray inside SecondClass is being contructed before this line is executed inside firstClass: firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:sec.secondArray]; If you fail to do this then secondArray will have a nil value, and will contain no objects to copy into firstArray.

Answer (score 0):

Just shouting out a suggestion from my head, but try `sec.array = secondarray`.

Comment: You might want to consider removing your comment, if your marking this post as the solution to your problem.